Non-intersecting $ABCD$ is a rectangle if $AB = CD$ and $BC = DA$ and $AC = BD$
I have been watching videos on how to build the base for a shed. The builders use lumber for two sides of the base (which are the same length) and different sized lumber for the other two sides.
To ensure the base is a rectangle, they measure the diagonals. If the diagonals are equal, the base is rectangular.

I am trying to prove this mathematically. Here’s what I have so far:
Given:

$ AB = CD $
$ AD = BC $

Proof:

If $ AC = BD $, then triangle $ \triangle ACD $ is congruent to triangle $ \triangle BCD )$.

And here I am stuck.
Any ideas on how to prove this?


Do we know if $AB$ is parallel to $CD$? If we had that, then we could use SAS to prove congruence.

@SeanRoberson No, that is unknow

Consider opposite interior angles like $\angle BAC$ and $\angle ACD$.

Why is $BD=AC$ not in "Given" ? Without that it's false: as a matter of fact $[AB=CD\land BC=AD]$ is equivalent to being a parallelogram.

@SassatelliGiulio, OP has chosen to express it as a condition in his if.

If $AC=BD$ (along with the Given), then you actually know four triangles that are mutually congruent.

Isn't this trivial by SSS?

FYI, as stated in the 2nd bullet point of Characterizations, having $2$ pairs or opposite sides each being equal in length is sufficient for the quadrilateral to be a parallelogram. Also, using a site search, there's Using vectors to show that if the diagonals of a parallelogram have the same length, then show that the parallelogram is a rectangle. using one technique to prove this.

All 4 triangles are congruent $\Delta ABC\cong\Delta ABD\cong\Delta ACD \cong \Delta BCD$. So $\angle A=\angle B=\angle C=\angle D$. The sum of all the angles is already known to be $2\pi$. (Consider sum of angles of $\Delta ABC + \Delta ACD$). So, each of those is $\pi/2$.

If we have $AB=CD$, $AD=BC$ and $AC=BD$, then $\triangle ABC\equiv \triangle CDA$.
This means that $\angle ABC=\angle ADC$, $\angle ACD=\angle CAB$ and $\angle ACB=\angle CAD$. The third equality implies that $AD||BC$. So $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
If a parallelogram is not a rectangle, one of the diagonals will be shorter. This is easy to see as the diagonal connecting the obtuse opposite angles will be shorter than the one between the acute opposite angles. This can be seen by applying the cosine law in a triangle formed with $2$ sides and one of the diagonals and the cosine law in a triangle with $2$ sides and the other diagonal. The sizes of the 2 outer edges will be the same (between the $2$ chosen triangles, respectively), but the cosine of the obtuse angle will be negative, leading to a longer diagonal since the cosine of the acute angle will be positive.
